# How to assign the same data but changing column value conditionally in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replace the values in a column based on certain condition and assign that data frame to another name. But every time i call the assigned name i get just the changed value , not the entire data. what am i missing here? I am a beginner, so cut me some slack :-)

```
test = data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10,c=7:11)
replaced = test$b[test$b>7& test$b<=9]=0
replaced
#[1] 0
```

when i call replaced, why don't i get the whole data set?

thank you!

Comment: Because `x <- y <- 0` sets both `x` and `y` to `0`.

Comment: Take a copy first `replaced <- test` - then do your replacement - `replaced$b[replaced$b>7& replaced$b<=9]=0`

Answer (score 1):

Just take a copy first and then replace:

```
test=data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10,c=7:11)
replaced <- test
replaced$b[replaced$b > 7 & replaced$b <= 9] <- 0
replaced

#  a  b  c
#1 1  6  7
#2 2  7  8
#3 3  0  9
#4 4  0 10
#5 5 10 11
```

Your original issue is due to the assignments running right to left:

```
x <- y <- 0
x
#[1] 0
y
#[1] 0
```

Doing a single assignment is ***much*** faster than looping over each row too:

```
test2 <- test[rep(1:5,3e4),]
nrow(test2)
#[1] 150000

system.time({
  replaced <- test2
  replaced$b[replaced$b>7& replaced$b<=9] <- 0
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 


system.time({
  i=1
  for ( i in 1:nrow(test2))
  { 
    if(test2[i,]$b>7& test2[i,]$b<=9){
     test2[i,]$b=0 
    }
  }
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 210.69    0.01  211.69
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this-

```
test=data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10,c=7:11)

i=1
for ( i in 1:nrow(test))
{ 
  if(test[i,]$b>7& test[i,]$b<=9){
   test[i,]$b=0 
  }
}
```

This would change values of b in the range of 8-9 to 0.